Trying to run first private RPC node on my PowerEdge R630 server, falling behind on PoH hashrate
Trying to run first RPC node for private use.
I know that my server has lower specs that recommended, but can’t figure out if I can make it work with current hardware setup or I need to update components.
My hardware :
CPU :2x Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2690 v4 @ 2.60GHz  , 14 core ( performance mode with clock speed set to 3.2 Ghz )
128 GB ddr4 ram with ECC enabled
Disk : 2x 1tb 6Gbps/s SSD's connected through Raid 0
All packaged in PowerEdge R630 server.
When running validator.sh failing to catchup with the speed of PoH hashes/second.
Max hashes/seconds i was able to squeeze out for now is : Mine 2904806, cluster target 10000000.
solana-cli 2.1.6
agave-validator 2.1.6
Is it possible to run it on that specs at all ?
Kinda lost on that point, any suggestions will be appreciated.
